# Rubyで作成したアプリをアップしているrennder.comのエラーの対処方が分かりません。

Tags: render.com

Render.comでアプリをアップしているのですが、アップしてから数日が経ちまして下記のような記述が出てきました。

```
This service is not ready to serve traffic. If you are the site owner, please check that your service is passing health checks.
```

こちらの対処方が探しているのですが、いまいちわかりかねるものばかりで困っています。

使っている言語はRubyです。

知っている方が居ましたら、教えて頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ステータスレポートで報告されている render の障害に該当するかもしれません

https://status.render.com/incidents/v5q42lcpll58

> it is recommended that you consider re-deploying your service to resolve the problem

とのことなのでデプロイしてみてはどうでしょうか

再発しているという話もあります

https://community.render.com/t/service-not-ready/11856/55